# Does sleep-talk with toddlers work?

Tags: toddler, sleep, research

Is there any scientific research that proves sleep-talk (reading affirmations to a child when the child sleeps) works? The promoters such as these https://gouldingprocess.com/  already say it does, but I want to be sure this is actually the case.

Comment: Hi folks, just a gentle reminder - please use comments to clarify the question rather than to give answers to it.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some detail to the question about WHAT "Sleep talk" is? (More than just the sentence that is there?) I clicked through but the site seemed more interested in selling the books than telling me what it actually IS.

Comment: @BunnyKnitter the question ALREADY says what sleep talk is ? Read what's between the brackets ( and )

Comment: @happybuddha Could you elaborate on this: "reading affirmations to a child when the child sleeps". Is it just repeating "You're a good kid, you're a good kid" or is it... "You didn't poop in your pants today, thats good". If you don't want to elaborate thats fine, but you might have more luck with answers if people understood what you are asking about.

Comment: I don't think there's any reliable evidence that sleeptalk works at -any- age...

Answer (score -1):

Google Scholar should be everyone's best friend for finding research results :)

Searching " "Sleep talk" hypnosis" (with "Sleep talk" in additional quotes to force google to find the exact phrase) yielded a lot of results about talking in one's sleep but about half way down the first page of results this gem came up:

> [Hypnosis for Children Using Direct and Indirect Approaches](http://search.proquest.com/openview/0bb7c3fb0b71dff1fb7d944031db27f9/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=30864)
>   Kakoschke, Celia. Australian Journal of Clinical Hypnotherapy and Hypnosis; Brisbane Vol. 28, Iss. 1,  (Autumn 2007): 39-44.

It appears to be directly referencing the "Sleep talk" as linked in the OP.

I don't have access to the full text but perhaps it can be requested through a library or local university or even just purchased if the interest is there. The introduction is available online at least and it confirms that it is on topic.

Comment: The question is "Does sleep-talk with toddlers work?" - does it?

Comment: @AnneDaunted Unfortunately I'm not willing to pay to buy the study to find the answer. The OP asked for a scientific resource, but many will be paywalled.

Comment: I'd be skeptical of this article in any case. From the first page it seems to be written by a practitioner and to be talking about their personal experience. So its probably just anecdote.